# ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I had to reinstall my pycharm and now when I try to run my Django server I get the following error:

```
(card_companion_venv) PS N:\My Drive\Projects\Card Companion\card_companion> python website/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=website.settings.base
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\My Drive\Projects\Card Companion\card_companion\website\manage.py", line 9, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\My Drive\Projects\Card Companion\card_companion\website\manage.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "N:\My Drive\Projects\Card Companion\card_companion\website\manage.py", line 11, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

The interpreter has the correct packages installed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

and the terminal is using the virtual environment:

```
(card_companion_venv) PS N:\My Drive\Projects\Card Companion\card_companion>
```

Comment: Seems that the virtualenvs are different: card_companion_venv vs card_companion

Comment: `card_companion` is the project folder which has `card_companion_venv`  which is the virtual environment where the packages are saved. There is a `website` folder in `card_companion` folder where I have the website files in.

Comment: is django installed in virtual env or in system python interpreter ?

Comment: Have you tried `File | Invalidate Caches / restart`? Is your `Run Configuration` pointing to the correct environment?

Comment: @VimalanE I have installed it at both system and virtual env level.

Comment: @nanotek I have run the invalidate cache and have added the run configuration screenshot to the question.